# How to add "no date" to bibtex item?

Tags: cross-referencing, natbib

I am trying to add "No Date" to a @misc bibtex item but for some reason I am not getting the result I want. I am referencing a webpate.

Here is my bib item:

```
@misc{endomondo,
author = {{Endomondo}},
year =      {no date},
howpublished = {\url{https://www.endomondo.com/features}},
note = {Accessed: 18 November 2016}
}
```

usage in text:

```
\citet[]{endomondo} – a sport tracking mobile
```

This gives the result:

[image]

Result in bibliography: 
[image]

Why "no date" is not appearing in the bibliography item? Anyone any ideas? Thank you in advance!

I am using

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib} % Use BibTeX for bibliography management
```

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use? Hint: the bibliography style, and not `natbib`, determines the formatting of all bibliographic items.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for your comment. I am using plainnat bibliography style. Do you think that is the problem?

Comment: I am unable to replicate the screenshot you've posted using the information you've provided. Specifically, in the formatted bib entry, the string "no date" is placed between the `howpublished` and `note` fields.

Comment: @Mico hmm, that's odd. I will have a better look at the code and correct my question as soon as I finish work.

Comment: @Mico everything is exactly what I have here. So you are getting "no date" in the rendered pdf in the  bibliography?

Comment: I've posted an "answer" to show the output I get using the information you've provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer. I will delete this answer eventually.)

I am unable to replicate the screenshot you've posted using the information you've provided. Specifically, in the formatted bib entry, the string "no date" shows up just fine between the contents of the `howpublished` and `note` fields.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{endomondo,
author = {Endomondo},
year   = {no date},
howpublished = {\url{https://www.endomondo.com/features}},
note   = {Accessed: 18 November 2016}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}
\citet{endomondo}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably you misunderstood me. The result you are getting is teh exact one I am getting. The " problem" is that there is no "no date" in the bibliography - it's just "Endomondo" and the url. My question was how to force latex to display "no date" not only in the text but in the bibliography

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev - I don't understand your point. The screenshots you and I have posted are not exactly the same. To wit, the string "no date" *is* present in in the formatted bibliography shown in my screenshot.

Comment: I just noticed it. My apologies! The reason I was confused was because I expected the string "no date" to appear right after "Endomondo", before the url. I am guessing that is being controlled by the bibliography style?

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev - *All* formatting details, and not just the placement of the contents of the `year` string, are controlled by the bibliography style you've selected.

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev - If you want the date string to come before the URL string, *don't use the `howpublished` field* to contain the URL information. Instead, use the field called `url`.